# Schemes to the rescue?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, noncommutative-algebra

I am reading chapter 1 of Gille and Szamuely's book *[Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/Livres/Gille-Szamuely-Central-simple-alg.pdf.pdf)*, on quaternion algebras. In it they prove (remark 1.3.1 on p. 18) that the conic associated to a quaternion algebra is an intrinsic invariant of the algebra, i.e. does not depend (at least up to isomorphism of the conic) on the basis chosen for the algebra. The argument *almost* convinces me, but not quite (see below). I am wondering if the ingredient that I need to convince me is to cast the argument in scheme-theoretic language. Thus, my first question is, can you help me formulate the argument in a way that speaks to my discomfort with it? My second question is, can we use schemes to do this?

**Background:** Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. The quaternion algebra

$$A = \binom{a,b}{k}$$

for $a,b\in k^\times$ is the four-dimensional associative $k$-algebra with basis $1,i,j,ij$ and (noncommutative) multiplication defined by $i^2=a, j^2=b, ij = -ji$; $1$ is identified with the unit of $k$. (Thus the usual Hamilton quaternions are the case $a=b=-1, k=\mathbb{R}$.) A change of basis is elements $1,i',j',i'j'$ in $A$ satisfying $i'^2=a', j'^2=b', i'j'=-j'i'$ for some (possibly different) $a',b'\in k^\times$. The subspace spanned by $i,j,ij$ does not depend on the basis since a calculation shows that this is exactly the set of elements of $A\setminus k$ whose square is $\in k$. This is called the subspace of *pure quaternions*.

The conic associated to $A$ is the conic in $\mathbb{P}^2_k$ defined by the form $ax^2+by^2-z^2$. Up to a simple substitution, this is the same as the conic defined by $ax^2+by^2-abz^2$.

$A$ is said to be *split* if it is isomorphic to $M_2(k)$. For example, if $a=1$, $A$ is split, because it can be mapped isomorphically onto $M_2(k)$ by

$$i\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}1& \\ &-1\end{pmatrix},\; j\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} &b\\ 1& \end{pmatrix}$$

A basic theorem says that $A$ is split if and only if the associated conic has a $k$-rational point.

**The argument:** Gille and Szamuely argue that changing basis in a quaternion algebra, which may change $a,b$, nonetheless does not change the isomorphism class of the associated conic. Their argument is essentially that the form $ax^2 + by^2 - abz^2$ which defines the conic is just given by squaring the pure quaternion $xi + yj + zij$. Since the space of pure quaternions is basis independent, so is this form, and thus so is the conic.

**My discomfort with it:** I like this argument, and I buy it in essence, but a detail troubles me. Namely, when I try to actually write down a basis-independent description of the conic, I come up empty (literally):

Okay, so the conic "is" the vanishing set in $\mathbb{P}_k^2$ of the form $ax^2+by^2 - abz^2$. Great, I can conceive of $\mathbb{P}_k^2$ as being the quotient of the space of pure quaternions by the scalar $k^\times$ action. Then the conic is the vanishing set of the form $\alpha^2$, where $\alpha$ is a pure quaternion.

The problem is this. In all interesting cases, i.e. whenever $A$ is not split, the conic I've just described is, as a set, *empty*. (Because the conic does not have $k$-rational points when $A$ is not split.) This empty set has lost the ability to distinguish between nonsplit nonisomorphic quaternion algebras, so it is not doing the job I came to it for.

This objection does not feel very substantive. The conic is not really the set of its $k$-rational points. (This seems like just the type of distinction that scheme theory is good at, hence the title of the question.)

**My question:** Clearly I need a more robust basis-independent description of the conic. I'd like it to be the $\operatorname{Proj}$ of $k[x,y,z]/(ax^2+by^2-abz^2)$, but this description is not basis-independent. Your thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $A$ is $k^4$ with additional structure.  Restrict the map $x \mapsto x^2$ to $k^4 \setminus (k\times 0 \times 0 \times 0) \to k^4$ and the pure quaternions are the preimage of $k \times 0 \times 0 \times 0$.  But $k^4$ are the rational points of $\mathbb A^4$.  You still have $x \mapsto x^2$ (it's algebraic) and you can still restrict this to $\mathbb A^4 \setminus(\mathbb A \times 0 \times 0 \times 0) \to \mathbb A^4$ and take the *scheme theoretic* preimage of $\mathbb A \times 0 \times 0 \times 0$.  The only assumptions this makes about the basis is that you choose $1$ as the first element.

Comment: Proj of $k[x,y,z]/(ax^2+by^2-abz^2)$ *is* basis-independent, because the quotient is just a ring, there's no bases in sight. Choosing bases is the same as choosing *generators* for the ring, i.e. stating that it is generated by the classes of say, $x,y,z$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer - I guess the question is how to be confident in a calculation-free way that changes of basis in the quaternion algebra correspond to changes of generators in $k[x,y,z]/(ax^2+by^2 - abz^2)$.

Comment: @Jim - when you talk about the scheme-theoretic preimage, I guess you mean the fiber product of the map $x\mapsto x^2$ by the closed embedding of $\mathbb{A}\times 0 \times 0 \times 0\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}^4$? So this should give a scheme-theoretic description of the pure quaternions. I want a scheme-theoretic description of the *conic*, so I guess you'd say replace $\mathbb{A}\times 0\times 0\times 0$ with $0\times 0 \times 0\times 0$ and do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is one thing you can do.  Another is to take the generic point of the pure quaternions (which is a well defined object now that they've been schemified) and square it.  This is now a well defined element which should give you the equations for the conic that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go all the way to schemes. You can use the following description of varieties over a non-algebraically closed field $k$ instead: loosely, such a variety $V$ is determined not just by its $k$-points but by its $L$-points for all algebraic extensions $L$ of $k$. More precisely, a variety over $k$ is a particularly nice functor from the category of algebraic extensions of $k$ to sets (the exact meaning of "particularly nice" depends on exactly what kind of varieties you want to capture and is not too important here; the exact meaning of "is" is that the functor from varieties over $k$ to this functor category is faithful).

So, here's the correct version of the construction you wanted to perform. Instead of just looking at $A$, look at $A \otimes_k L$ for all $L$, then run the construction you just ran and check that it's functorial in $L$. Then check, using a basis, that it's the conic you expected.